# How can I match a regex at the beginning _or_ end of the line?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a JS regex that matches `!next` either at the beginning *or* end of the line.

Currently I'm using `/(^!next|!next$)/i` which works. However that's obviously kind of ugly to read and not DRY, so I'm looking to improve.

The closest I've come is this:

`/(?=!next)[^$]/i`

But that actually just matches everything (and it occurs to me now that I misremembered the way that `^` works inside character classes, so this solution is garbage anyway).

I've searched the web and SO, and I'm totally stumped.

Comment: You could leave off those parentheses, but your first expression is just fine. `^` inside `[]` means not any one character.

Comment: The original way is much easier to understand at a glance. If there are other developers involved I'd stick with that.

Comment: You could built the regexp dynamically with `function beginningOrEnd(str) { return new Regexp(\`^${str}|${str}\$\`, 'i'); }`, then call it with `beginningOrEnd("!next")`.

Comment: Why are you escaping the exclamation mark?

Comment: @torazaburo good question. it's based on a regexp that someone else authored in a PR and I copypasta'd without noticing.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fun one, using regex conditionals:

```
/(^)?!next(?(1)|$)/gm
```

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/54mXuy/1)

How it works is it captures the beginning-of-line anchor, and, if it is not present, matches the end-of-line anchor instead.

Personally, though, I'd still argue in favour of your solution over mine because it's more readable to someone who doesn't have an extremely thorough knowledge of regexes (and is more portable).

For added fun, here's another version (that's even uglier than your initial variant):

```
/!next(?:(?<=^.{5})|(?=$))/gm
```

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/54mXuy/4)

I'd still recommend sticking with the classic alternation, though.

And, finally, one that works in JS (no, really):

```
/(?:^|(?=.{5}$))!next/gm
```

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/p3L89M/1)

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I'm willing to bet OP's initial way is technologically faster.

Comment: @PHPglue: [According to Regex101, you're right (58 steps vs. 86)](https://regex101.com/r/54mXuy/2), but the OP asked for a DRY-ish regex, not a fast one. Note that I argue in favour of his solution as opposed to my own. I'm actually interested why the alternation variant has less steps now...

Comment: I can't get that to work in regexp101 specifying the JS flavor.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz the second one is... truly horrifying. but nice :P

Comment: @torazaburo. No. JavaScript doesn't support conditionals. The second version also doesn't work because JS doesn't support lookbehind assertions, either.

Comment: Plus one for extreme creativity, however misplaced.

Comment: @torazaburo: I came up with a JS-compatible one, just for you :P

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
function beginningOrEnd(input, search) {
  const pos = input.search(search);
  return pos === 0 || pos === input.length - search.length;
}

beginningOrEnd("hey, !help", "!help");
```

This uses `search.length`, so obviously `search` must be a string.

Or, you could construct the regexp yourself:

```
function beginningOrEnd(search) {
  return new RegExp(`^${search}|${search}\$`, "i");
}

beginningOrEnd("!help").test(input)
```

In the real world, you'd want to escape special regexp characters appropriately, of course.

Comment: Very nice. The first version obviously only works if you restrict `search` to literal strings, not regexes.